# how to create bootstrap html library from a template or a snippet with placeholders to change classes easily?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, code-snippets

I am currently using c# to make functions that i provide with parameters to control bootstrap elements such as buttons and tables. Here is an example,

```
Buttons button = new Buttons();
simple_button = button.addSimpleButton("red", "simpleButton", "large", "google.com","", "test");
```

this approach is very hard to follow and time consuming to create and maintain.
Is there a simpler way to do this as a function or a snippet with placeholders to change what you want with simple options?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not creating the button in C# would help.  Why don't you just make the button in a view and be done with it?  What does this method gain you?

Comment: this is true for one or simple projects. What i want is a simple way to create this button multiple times with different options. 
also, creating the element using code allow modification and customization at run time.

Comment: It's equally true for large projects as well.  Create buttons in the front-end where they belong.  Instead, pass in JSON to configure the buttons on the front-end, then have JS code process that JSON into buttons.  Don't create buttons in C#.  Doing so gains you nothing and makes things harder to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this library for asp.net development
Html Agility Pack (HAP)
http://html-agility-pack.net/

it has ready functions to parse the html so it might help.
good luck.